# Sending Data over UDP through Node

Tags: ros, ethernet, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a possiblity to send Data through UDP over a ROS Node?

To Specify my question:
I have a Non-ROs Computer who provides odometry who sends through UDP the data and I want to write a ROS Node which listens to this data.

Also I want to build a ROS Node who sends data through ethernet to the non-ros computer!

thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207677/sending-data-over-udp-through-node/) by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 201 on 2015-04-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sure. You are free to do anything you want in a ROS node. Just open a UDP socket (using basic C/C++ std runtime support, or Boost, or X ..) and use it like you would normally do.

The only 'restriction' would be that you'd have to give ROS a chance to process its events and do some bookkeeping once in a while. A typical pattern for that is something like:

```
while (your_own_termination_condition && ros::ok())
{
   handle_your_udp_traffic();

   // other stuff
   ..

   // let ROS do its thing
   ros::spinOnce();

   // maybe sleep a little (but that depends on your application)
   ..
}
```

If I understand your [other question](http://answers.ros.org/question/207671/made-urdf-file-whats-next/) correctly, the 'other stuff' would probably include things like converting the odometry data from your motor controller into proper ROS msgs, and any incoming ROS msgs (most likely [geometry_msgs/Twist](http://docs.ros.org/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html)) into data you can send to your motor controller over your UDP socket.

---

Edit: you might also be interested in using [ros_control](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_control) to base your own node on. Instead of implementing all of the ROS side yourself, you provide `ros_control` with a `hardware_interface` (which in your case would implement the communication with your motor controller over UDP) and 'the rest' (twist controllers, differential drive velocity calculation, and the associated ROS API) will be provided for you. If I'm not mistaken, the [husky_control](http://wiki.ros.org/husky_control) pkg is similarly implemented.

See [davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate](https://github.com/davetcoleman/ros_control_boilerplate) for an example of how to set this up.

I sort of assumed here that you're trying to create a differential-drive mobile robot (as you talk about odometry), but if not, `ros_control` can still be useful.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-04-23**:
that was pretty helpful! I have no knowledge about udp sockets but I have to learn it now, thanks for your fast answer :)

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-04-24**:
Do I need to download boost or is it already included in ROS?
I am trying now to open a UDP Socket via Boost in a Ros node!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-24**:
Boost is not 'included', but it is a dependency, so it will be installed whenever you install ROS. For your own pkg, I'd recommend adding a `depend` element to your manifest (see the [catkin docs](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/catkin/html/howto/format2/system_library_dependencies.html)).

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-04-27**:
okay, I worked a lot and I finally get the odometry out and I am publishing the encoderdata into ros to lwheel and rwheel. I found the differential drive package which would've transformed my encoder values into odometry but I just saw it is for groovy and I am using indigo. Can I still use it or is

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-04-27**:
I think you got the [differential_drive](http://wiki.ros.org/differential_drive) confused with the `ros_control` based [ros_controllers/diff_drive_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/diff_drive_controller) package. The last one is a completely different pkg, and is the one I recommend you use.

**Comment by [felixwatzlawik](https://answers.ros.org/users/22115/felixwatzlawik/) on 2015-04-28**:
got the Odometry running, how can I get my URDF Representation in rviz?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-05-03**:
There are plenty of tutorials on how to do that. In any case, it's probably better to post a new question than to keep adding to this one ('urdf representation' is rather different from 'sending data over udp').

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2016-01-01**:
@gvdhoorn,  [Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/223345/using-udp-to-transport-the-subscribers-messages/) is the problem which likes this problem a little but the situation is opposite. Could you click the link to see my question? Thank you so much.

**Comment by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on 2017-04-18**:
Hi @felixwatzlawik
It seems that I have the same problem as your because I want to read some encoders output through UDP. I would be grateful if you could help me solve this issue. My email address is: mas.fazeli2001@gmail.com.

**Comment by [Masoud](https://answers.ros.org/users/26841/masoud/) on 2017-04-18**:
I also found this package.
https://github.com/abhinavjain241/comm_tcp

but it is using TCP/IP protocols to communicate while I need UDP.